# Finding txt File path dynamically

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, vbscript, path

I need to read a txt file but I don't have the path. The text file is two directories before the path of the script I'm running. I thought I could use "WScript.ScriptFullName" and then just use an instrRev and make it split the str at "/". But It doesn't work Could you guys help me with that. I have to run this on multiple computers so the path changes but the text file will always be two derictories above the script path

My code so far

```
Dim strScriptPath
strScriptPath = Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "")
WScript.Echo strScriptPath
WScript.Echo(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Dim DashRev
DashRev = instrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "/")
wscript.echo DashRev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace the `"/"` with `"\"`

Then try the following. This seems to work for me:

```
Dim strScriptPath
strScriptPath = Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "")
WScript.Echo strScriptPath
WScript.Echo(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Dim first, sec
first = instrRev(strScriptPath, "\",Len(strScriptPath)-1)
sec = instrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\",first-1)
wscript.Echo "parent = " & Left(strScriptPath,sec)
```

The idea being that `strScriptPath` is always going to end in `"\"` and `first` is going to exclude that from the `instrrev` by using the starting position of one less than the length of the path. Same thing essentially with `sec`.

Comment: Thanks that exactly what I needed, Sorry about the dumb "/" mistake, Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Echo FSO.GetFile(WScript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder.ParentFolder.ParentFolder.Path
```